# How to change URL scheme in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My URL's at the moment are like this `http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html#/login`

I want them to be like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/login`

I route the URLs like this:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
  })

 });
```

I've tried setting `html5Mode` to true like this:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
  })
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 });
```

But this seems to not work.

For example, when I click `<a ng-href="#/login">login</a>` the first time the page loads but all other hyperlinks like `<a ng-href="#/register">Register</a>` get turned into `http://127.0.0.1:8080/login#/register`

Comment: I think you also need update your HTML to not contain links with #